# Change terminal color in solaris 10

Tags: solaris, colors, gnome-terminal

I installed Solaris 10, but I want change the background terminal color to black.
Is there any way to see my text in color mode with vi editor too?

Comment: What terminal are you using? `dtterm` or any other?

Comment: I use Gnome terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default colors of your terminal emulator, whether it is `dtterm`, `gnome-terminal` or even `xterm` (reverse-video), using its configuration menu.

Solaris 10 standard System V `vi` doesn't support syntax coloring. You need to install and use `vim` or `elvis` to get it.

Comment: where is its option in gnome-treminal?

Comment: Should be somethng like: Right click / Profiles / Profile preferences / Colors

Comment: there is nothing like this.

Comment: Then: Edit / Current Profile / Colors